# Responsive Cross Browser and Flexible way of "cross-background" images

Tags: css

Can anyone please point me out, or name some tecnhiques that may exist in order to achieve this effect, on a properly way:

Like this:

[image]

and again:

[image]

As you may notice, the point is to connect both lines. Some of those lines come from text boxes, that, since we wish to properly use EM unit for font-size, the box around the text, may change.

I have never done this before, I would appreciate any point outs, in order to investigate this "effect" further please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t know what effect you’re talking about.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I've try to explain it further after the images. Is it more clear now? Thanks. - Again, I've never done this before. It could be trivial, and perhaps I'm over complicating things here. But I believe, this is not easily done if we consider the EM fonts inside text boxes, text box lines that will grow together with the text, and still need to visually connect.

Comment: This is just a matter of positioning DIVs with a the proper background images.  Otherwise, you use html 5 canvas or something to draw some dotted lines (more complex).

Comment: @user1477388 - Please notice the text box with the text: "Contribua com o que pode divulgue muito" Now, imagine that the user ZOOMS the text, and the font is on EM. If we do that, the box will need to grow. If the box grow, the dotted line will expand. As far as I can tell, that will not trigger the background of the container element to move accordingly. So, I believe this is NOT just a question of adjusting the background divs. Or I'm see it wrong? Please advice.

Comment: Do you have an online example of this that I can see?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the fonts in the text boxes are in EM. If the font size change, the text boxes size will change, but that it doesn't mean that the space between them also has to change (it could has a fixed height -the background height-).

Here's a really basic example (try changing the body font-size):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { font-size: 12px;}
      .text { border: 1px solid #999; padding: 15px; font-size:1em; }
      .line { background: url(http://www.agavegroup.com/images/articles/photoshopCurvedLine/curveFinal.gif) no-repeat center center; height: 50px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Eum, quis consequuntur culpa ex eius totam nemo.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you do want the space between boxes height changing if the font-size change, you should set it height to EM and use a background images that's, lets say, doubled the container original height (so when the height change, more background it's revealed). You can see this changing **height: 50px;** to **height: 7em;** on the .line {} rule (the example image I've used it higher than the container).

This a really basic example. The markup depends on the design. If you need something more accurate (like: you need that the line starts and ends in specific spot), you should probably use absolute/relative positions.